# How to prevent f12 and print screen keys using typescript in angular 6 web application

Tags: angular, web-applications, angular6

How to prevent f12 and print screen keys using typescript in angular 6 web application.Tried adding js files but the document events are not getting triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine the following together.

- Print Screen key's keycode is 44.
- F12 key's keycode is 123.
- To prevent the default behavior of the key, call `Event#preventDefault` method on the event instance.
- To bind an event to the `document` (opposed to a specific element visible in the template), use the `@HostListener` decorator with the `document:` prefix.
- To bind events across the whole application, use the root application component (usually `AppComponent`).

So, what you want to do is something along the following lines.

```
@Component(/* ... */)
export class AppComponent {
  // ...

  @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
  onKeyUp (event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode == '44' || event.keyCode == '123') {
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  }
}
```

Note, however, that your "security measures" are futile and will only drive the users insane when they really want to use a feature. Also, OS/Browser might not care for your intentions in some cases (which is the correct approach). Nothing can stop a user to open the developer tools (eg. in Chrome you can also open it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>, or by using the browser's UI). For "stealing" images, the developer tools is a far more convenient tool over taking screenshots.